# Framework products location

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, ios-frameworks

I created a "Cocoa touch framework" in x-code and built it

After getting a successful build i look inside the "products" directory and there are no *.framework file further more on the files are colored in red

Where is the framework files?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to press `command` + `B` in `Xcode` (Build the product) with it's suitable target - this will build your framework. If you haven't built it already (or deleted the files manually or clean the products directory with `Xcode`), the files are coloured in red, since they haven't been created yet.